# Application Insights for WPF application in OFFLINE mode

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, analytics, azure-application-insights

when internet connection is available application insights for wpf application works fine and I am able to track page and events in azure portal but I want to know is it possible to store telemetry data somewhere in system when their is no internet connection and retrieve it when system is online and track those actions which I performed when their was no internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Persistence-Channel or Server-Channel for this scenario:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PersistenceChannel
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel